# Should I throw exception to indicate no access?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception

I have a service that generates digital documents to the user. I have created a payment system that the user use to buy access to generate digital documents (among other things).

If the user tries to generate a digital document but have no access should I throw an exception (unchecked or checked?) or would it be better to return an Optional object where value not present means that the user does not have access?

This code is in the service layer of my application. I am unsure what to do here. I am exposing this service as a RESTful service, so I can only assume that it will be called by clients where the users does not have access. In the WEB-layer I am intercepting this and I create an error resource that I respond with.

Comment: Why not return HTTP status 403 Forbidden to indicate user is unauthenticated to the resource.

Comment: Yeah...but how do I know that in the web layer if the service layer does not tell the web layer that something wrong happend? By magic?

Comment: I think is JGrice solution is nice. You can throw 403 + textual information that it's due the fact user did not pay or something.

Comment: Actually, if you're trying to follow convention, return HTTP 401 Unauthorized, as this indicates you need to login, 403 indicates the resource is unavailible to everyone

Comment: These comments are non sense.